# Why does hot code replace fail in Eclipse while debugging a web application running in Tomcat 7?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat, tomcat7

Everything went well when I was using Tomcat 6. Now I am connecting the debugger to a web application deployed in Tomcat 7 using Eclipse 3.6.1. The project's "Build automatically" feature is turned on. I only add a line like `System.out.println("why does hot code replace not work?");` and the Eclipse error dialog appears saying hot code replace failed. Again, using Tomcat 6 I didn't experience this behavior. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just tried this out under Eclipse 3.6.2, Tomcat 7.0.14 and Oracle JDK 6 update 21. It works for me, even with auto-redeployment enabled for the project (a dynamic web module v3.0). You might want to check [this site](http://blog.redfin.com/devblog/2009/09/how_to_set_up_hot_code_replacement_with_tomcat_and_eclipse.html) out.